# Question regarding Batch class

Tags: apex, batch

I want to query all fields in the start method of the batch class. Below is my code which is giving error(also giving error on type casting). Can you please suggest if there is any way to achieve this?

```
global class BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) { 
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> CaseMap = Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();        
        Set<String> setFieldNames = CaseMap.keySet();
        list<String> lstFieldNames = new List<String>(setFieldNames);                
        String query = Database.query('SELECT ' + String.join(lstFieldNames, ',') + ' FROM Case limit 2');
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Database.getQueryLocator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_getQueryLocator_2) method will directly accept a SOQL query string so:

```
String query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(lstFieldNames, ',') + ' FROM Case limit 2';
return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
```

or to keep security scanners happy about [SOQL injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm):

```
String query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(lstFieldNames, ',') + ' FROM Case limit 2';
return Database.getQueryLocator(String.escapeSingleQuotes(query));
```